Confused, the AS5047P sensor allows for perpendicular positioning? So the edge of a diametric ring magnet will work?
I have a rod that is suspended by two bearings.
For the rotation to be measured I'd like to add a diametric ring magnet to the rod and have the sensor read the outer edge of that ring.
Will the AS5047 work?
Here is a mockup of what I mean.
Thanks in advance.


The OSRAM AnglePositionOnAxis AN000271 application note describes how the AS5047P High-Resolution Position Sensor works.
In the application note the magnet is always shown rotating over the chip. E.g.:

1.2 Measurement principle
ams’ magnetic position sensor products uses a patented differential measurement principle. These circuits are using integrated lateral Hall sensors in standard CMOS technology. Lateral Hall elements are sensitive to the magnetic field component perpendicular to their surface. This means they are only sensitive to magnetic fields vertical to the IC surface. The magnetic flux density in z–direction Bz is measured and horizontal Bx and By components are not measured at all.

The magnetic position sensor circuits are a system-on-chip, they contain all components required to create a non-contact rotation angle position measurement system. Basically, the only external component required is a magnet rotating over the surface of the IC. Depending on the use case
(target accuracy, vertical air gap, temperature range and mounting possibilities), different magnets are used.
In this type of measurement, a magnet rotates over the chip such that

the center of the magnet,
the center of rotation
and the center of the chip

are in one vertical line (see Figure 1).

Given the measurement principle used I would say proposed orientation in the question, which effectively tilts the magnet by 90 degrees, will not work.

From a comment:

Would you know of any type of sensor that would work as shown in the mockup picture? VIdeodrome

A search found Triaxis®: Unique sensing solution which starts with:

Triaxis® is an innovative magnetic sensor technology capable of very precise three axis magnetic field measurements from a single sensor. Endless linear, angular and 3D applications can be developed.

There is a picture of a Off-axis setup which is like the mock-up from the question:




Thank you. I was afraid of this..
Would you know of any type of sensor that would work as shown in the mockup picture? Appreciated.

@VIdeodrome I have updated the answer with a possible type of sensor

I was looking at off-axis only solutions but the MLX90930 seems the way to go.
The extended range makes placement also a breeze. Thank you.
